# Generate unique key based on tree hierarchy

Tags: java

I have a similar problem to the one addressed in the stackoverflow article ([Creating a java hierarchial treeset from a flat list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9472087))

What I am currently attempting to do is print the tree to a file, with the following:

- The parents need to be printed out first, so if they're imported (somewhere) they get created first so the children can then be created under them.
- I need to generate a unique key based on the hierarchy for example:

  Root > Parent > Child > GrandChild1

  Root > Parent > Child > GrandChild2

`>` is a delimiter for nodes, but don't really mind what this is...

Is someone able to suggest a way that I can generate the unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by the key, etc... but it sounds trivial.

To print a tree using the root first use prefix print

Here is how you print prefix (this tree has numbers, but it shouldn't matter, you get the idea).  The method below uses recursion.

```
private void printPrefix(Node<?> node){

        //If node is null, reached end of chain, return to caller
        if (node==null) {
            return;
        }

        //Print self
        System.out.print(node.getValue());
        System.out.print(" ");

        //Print all children
         for (Source child : node.children) //changed for multiple
{
    printPrefix(child);
}

        return;
    }
```

On a better datastructure suggestion, you should consider a b-tree.
https://www.google.com/search?q=b+tree&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#itp=open0

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My structure doesn't have left and right nodes so how would I use the above?

Comment: Changed to address multiple children