# How to sort data in Firestore according to a property?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database full with cars. The `JSON` format is this:

```
docId: {
        "city": "Amsterdam"
        ... other properties
   }
```

The `docId` is a key generated by the `add` function.

I query the database like so:

```
db.collection("EU-CARS").whereEqualTo("city", "Amsterdam");
```

And I get all cars that are available in Amsterdam but I want to get something like this:

```
Amsterdam
    docId
    docId
Utrecht
    docId
    docId
```

Each city with the corresponding cars. How to solve this without creating a query for each city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `orderBy()`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#orderBy(java.lang.String)

So you would do:

```
db.collection("EU-CARS").orderBy("city")
```

You will get the following

```
docId1
   city: Amsterdam
   ...
docId2
   city: Amsterdam
   ...
docId3
   city: Utrecht
   ...
docId4
   city: Utrecht
   ...
```

and it will be up to you to transform that, in your front-end, to the exact format you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but how can I get output as in my question? city name, cars, again city name and again cars?

Comment: Just loop on the result in your java code and each time the city is different from the previous record, create a new category. You will easily find some examples or inspiration on the web, for example https://www.java-success.com/00-%E2%99%A6-creating-tree-list-flattening-back-list-java/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472087/creating-a-java-hierarchial-treeset-from-a-flat-list or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383869/converting-flat-structure-to-hierarchical (to be adapted to java) or https://www.google.com/search?q=java+build+tree+from+flat+list